# Recursive Function To Help Clear Tiles (Field Of View)

Tags: python, recursion

I am attempting to teach myself python and have hit a rough spot once it has come to recursion. I have done the classic recursive functions (factorial, fibonacci numbers...) but I am going back over old code and trying to convert most of my iterative functions to recursive functions for practice.

This is the wall that I have hit:

I made a dungeon crawler a while back and I am trying to replace a for loop I used to reveal the squares near my sprite. So when the sprite is placed, he/she sees the tile he/she is on as well as the adjacent and diagonal squares (9 in total including the one the avatar is on).The other tiles making up the room are hidden. This I deemed view radius 1. For view radius 2, I wanted the char to see radius 1 squares plus all the tiles adjacent to those tiles. At the time I could not figure out how to do it with a for loop so I just implemented a simpler scheme.

I feel this visibility function could be written recursively but I am having a hard time coming up with a base case and what my recursive step would be. My for loop just took avatar pos and iterated over a range to avatar pos + radius and I did that for the x,y coordinates.

As far as translating this over to a recursive function I am really confused. I have done many searches trying to get a lead but only come up with complicated subjects such as: FOV using recursive shadowcasting which is way beyond me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to make it recursive? .... if its readable in its current form ... you almost certainly wont have time gains by converting from iterative to recursive ... (for this case at least)

Comment: I am doing it to for 2 reasons: 1) I could not implement my original vision described above with a for loop ( I ended up just making view radius into fixed tiles radiating from avatar) 2) I think I can implement what I originally wanted with recursion. I have learned a lot tackling this problem and hopefully ends with learning to implement my original idea.

Answer (score 1):

I find it helps a LOT to express recursions in words. What the algorithm says is basically "what's visible at radius N is what's visible from radius N-1". Like, uh, the edge gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
def visible(pos, radius, seen):
    if radius == 1:
        # base case
        seen.add(...)
        yield ...
    else:
        for center in visible(pos, radius-1, seen):
            for x in visible(center, 1, seen):
                if x not in seen:
                    seen.add(x)
                    yield x
```

`seen` would be a `set`. Each time you call `visible` "from the outside" you'd supply an empty set:

```
visible(pos, radius, set())
```

The `seen` set could also be initialized to implement fog of war (or at least oddly unseeable squares ;) )...